# Contractor scratched, gouged, and pitted my new hardwood floors

Tags: contractors

The contractor that installed my beautiful new hardwood floors then scratched, gouged, and pitted them when dragging our new kitchen cabinetry across them.  He's trying to tell me that those dings are, "normal".  My brand new floor is scratched to heck!

The guys that he had install the cabinetry didn't use any blankets.

What are my options?

Comment: Option 1 - Don't pay him ...

Comment: @brhans won't he put a lean on my house in that situation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal/contractual matter and not about home improvement.

Comment: If he is a licensed contractor he will be governed by a city, county , or state agency who has reporting procedures for disputes.  Also the BBB is still a factor in issue with businesses.

Comment: He would have to put a lien on your house at the beginning of the project and you would have had to sign off on it - so if he hasn't done that already then no.

Comment: Liens are for debts owed.  No debt is owed at the beginning of a project.

Comment: @brhans Not true in either state I deal with.  One state I must file full liens within a specific window of time based the date of invoice, not before 31 days after invoice date and before the 90th day (meaning day 89 really).  In the other state I can file an "intent to lien" without filing a full lien.   In any case, your comment is incorrect because it varies by AHJ.

Comment: Contact a lawyer, not a bunch of schmoes on the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make a complaint in writing and mail it signed return receipt (to prove it was sent and received).

-Make it short, specific as to the details (when, what, how, who, where), and make references to any violations or applicable sections of the written work contract regarding damages to property.

-Avoid emotions, threats, etc. while writing it.  It may be seen by a small claims judge or mediator so make is sound like it was written by a lawyer (they like such things).

2) Take pictures.  Use a artificial light at an angle with a tape measure next to each significant damage.  The angled light will let the damage show better and the tape measure will document the size.

3) Get 3 quotes of what it would cost to repair the floor; obviously not from the guy who damaged them.

4) Be careful about what you do or do not pay the contractor.  Don't pay for the flooring (if you haven't already).

-You might want to put all money normally due the contractor in a separate bank acct.  This will show a judge/mediator that you're not just trying to avoid paying or trying to renegotiate contracted costs.

5) *After* you have done #1-4 above, negotiate with the contractor re: repairing the floor (if possible...laminate floors or floors with a thin wear layer can't be repaired or repaired and still be worth their original new value).